# Object within state is changing without being prompted

Tags: reactjs

I'm using setState to update a particular object but for some reason, another object is being mutated as well even though I haven't added it in the setState function.

Basically I have an 'add to cart' function, if item already exists in cart state object, just increments it's quantity by 1. If not, update state of cart with a copy that contains said item.

```
this.state = {
  items: {
    0: { name: 'Red shirt', price: 10 },
    1: { name: 'Blue shirt', price: 11 },
    2: { name: 'Green shirt', price: 12 },
    3: { name: 'Yellow shirt', price: 13 }
  },
  cart: {},
  user: {}
}

addToCart = (key, item) => {
 let newCart;
 newCart = this.state.cart;

 // item already exists in cart
 if (newCart[key]) {
  // increment qty of added item
  newCart[key].qty++;
  // does not exist, need to add to cart
 } else {
  newCart[key] = item;
  newCart[key].qty = 1;
 }
 this.setState({ cart: newCart });
}

  render() {
const { cart, items } = this.state;
return (
  <div className="App">
    <h1>Streat</h1>
    <Checkout cart={cart} />
    <Items
      items={items}
      addToCart={this.addToCart}
    />
  </div>
);
}
}

// Items component which holds Item component
class Items extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
}

render() {
    const { items, addToCart } = this.props;
    return (
        <div>
            {
                map(items, function renderItems(item, key) {
                    return <Item
                        item={item}
                        itemRef={key}
                        key={key}
                        addToCart={addToCart} />
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}
}

// Item functional component which has the add to cart button
const Item = (props) => {
const { item, itemRef, addToCart } = props;
return (
    <div>
        <p>{item.name}</p>
        <p>{item.price}</p>
        <p>{item.qty || ""}</p>
        <button onClick={() => addToCart(itemRef, item)}>Add</button>
    </div>
)
}
```

When inspecting the state of my items object in react developer tools, I see that every time I click the button to add an item to the cart, it does correctly add the item to the cart / update the quantity of the item but it also updates the item in the items object in my state, adding a 'qty' key/ value pair which is not what I want.

I'm using setState on my cart object but my items object is being changed too for some reason.

Comment: can you add you total code

Comment: @Geeky done :)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to update your state by using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) so you don't get into this kind of trouble. [Redux](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingObjectSpreadOperator.html) also uses that a lot. By doing it you don't mutate your object and create a clean copy of them.

Your code is not *copying* the item on line (`newCart[key] = item;`). Instead, it is putting a reference from the same item and by changing the `qty` in the next line you consequently update it as well in the `items` key.

```js
const Item = ({ name, price, onClick }) =>
  <div onClick={onClick}>
    {name} {price}
  </div>

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      items: {
        0: { name: 'Red shirt', price: 10 },
        1: { name: 'Blue shirt', price: 11 },
        2: { name: 'Green shirt', price: 12 },
        3: { name: 'Yellow shirt', price: 13 }
      },
      cart: {},
      user: {}
    }
  }
  
  addToCart(key, item) {
    const hasItem = this.state.cart[key]
    
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      cart: {
        ...this.state.cart,
        [key]: {
          ...(hasItem ? this.state.cart[key] : item),
          qty: hasItem ? this.state.cart[key].qty + 1 : 1,
        },
      },
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { cart, items } = this.state
     
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Click to add:</div>
        {Object.keys(items).map(key =>
          <Item
            {...items[key]}
            key={key}
            onClick={this.addToCart.bind(this, key, items[key])}
          />
        )}
        
        <div style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
          {Object.keys(cart).map(key =>
            <div key={key}>{cart[key].name}:{cart[key].qty}</div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Not sure if that block was meant to be a legitimate solution (didnt work) or was just a suggestion. I'll try look into the spread syntax way and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: @jonathanpuc yes, it is a solution. Check my working sample :)

Comment: Wooh it works, thank you.

I don't quite understand what's going on here though :

            [key]: {
          ...(hasItem ? this.state.cart[key] : item),
          qty: hasItem ? this.state.cart[key].qty + 1 : 1,
        }

I don't get how the spread operator is being used on the 2nd line. Could you please explain? :)

Comment: Sure. As `cart` is an object, `key` is responsible for handling which property within `cart` should be updated. If `hasItem` is `true`, then spread existing item at `key`.. otherwise spread the item coming from argument so a new entry is created in `cart`. And the same logic is applied for setting `qty` on that item.